# Uniqueness of branch of logarithm.

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts

This was a problem from Freitag's Complex Analysis,

> A continuous function $l: D \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $D$ open connected subset of $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0 \}$, is called a continuous branch of log if $\exp ^{l(z)}= z $ for all $z \in D$.
>
> **Show:** On $D$ there exists a unique continuous branch of the logarithm only if the function $1/z$ has primitive on $D$.

I know we can work locally: if $l$ is primitive, and $l'=1/z$, then on $\bar{B}(a,\epsilon)$ take an analytic branch $L_\varepsilon$ defined on this domain, we deduce $\exp^{l(z)}=z $ for all $z \in B(a,\varepsilon)$.

So $l$ is in fact a continuous branch.

---

This seems a bit counter intuitive. Wouldn't any $\bar{l} = l +2 \pi k i$ be another continuous branch on $D$? Then why *uniqueness*?

Comment: Yes, if $l$ is a branch of the logarithm on $D$, then so is $z \mapsto l(z) + 2k\pi i$ for every $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. We get uniqueness if we specify the value at one point.

Comment: But the problem doesn't specify a value, why do we have "unique continuous branch"?

Comment: It's a mistake or mistranslation. If one continuous branch of the logarithm exists on a domain, then countably many exist.